# Numba. How to open files

Tags: python, numba

I'm working with this function:

```
def read_example(water_bound, filename, conditions):

    f = open(filename,"r")
        for i in range(0, conditions):

            lines = f.readline()

            test = map(int, lines.split('            '))

            water_bound.append( test[0]-1 )
```

and I wanna be able to use it with `numba`. As far as I understand from [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.6/doc/types.html), I must add this line before my function declaration:

```
@jit('void(int32[:], c_string_type, int32 )',nopython=True)
```

However, I got this error:

> NameError: name 'c_string_type' is not defined

Comment: Numba does not generically speed-up python code. You'll likely get no performance gain doing something like file IO. If your code is working on scalar values or arrays or possibly lists with elements of homogenous type, then numba is fantastic. What you are trying to do here will fall back to python object mode which will be the same speed as python and possibly a bit slower.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably have a look at the [numba documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.24.0/reference/pysupported.html) which explains which python features are supported. These are the features that are supported in `nopython` mode (which actually speeds things up in comparison to python):

- Most language constructs are (`for`, `if`, etc.) including generators
- (Almost) Every numerical type
- tuples
- homogeneous lists
- a lot of math and numpy stuff

but file i/o is not supported. So you need can `jit` your function but it will fail with `nopython` mode.

Just analyzing your function will make it clear that you will not get any speed up:

- File I/O will fallback to python (slow) mode:

  ```
  f = open(filename,"r")
  ```
- This for loop would work with `nopypthon` mode since it is supported (if everything inside the loop could be compiled with numba constructs):

  ```
  for i in range(0, conditions):
  ```
- Unfortunatly readline is again File I/O and not supported:

  ```
      lines = f.readline()
  ```
- String operations like `split` cannot be compiled in `nopython` mode either:

  ```
      test = map(int, lines.split('            '))
  ```
- If (and only if) your list `water_bound` would contain only numbers and you wanted to append another number it should work (see [numba list reference](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.24.0/reference/pysupported.html#list)) but with strings I cannot get it on my computer to compile with `nopython`.

  ```
      water_bound.append( test[0]-1 )
  ```

So you might be able to `jit` your function but since it falls back to python mode you don't need to bother with `signatures` (because they only start to matter if you go into the fast nopython mode) and very likely you will not see any speed benefit:

```
from numba import jit
@jit
def read_example_numba(water_bound, filename, conditions):
    f = open(filename,"r")
    for i in range(0, conditions):
        lines = f.readline()
        test = map(int, lines.split('            '))
         water_bound.append( test[0]-1 )
```

on my computer with some randomly generated file it takes:

> With jit: 10000 loops, best of 3: 78.1 ms per loop
>   Without jit: 10000 loops, best of 3: 71.4 ms per loop

You should probably take a look on the [Numba Documentation Examples](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.24.0/user/examples.html) they show which kind of functions can be speed up.